# how to search and display specific line from a text file vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, line

Hi I am trying to search for a line which contains whats the user inputs in a text box and display the whole line. My code below doesnt display a  messsagebox after the button has been clicked and i am not sure if the record has been found

```
   Dim filename, sr As String
    filename = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + "\" + "mul.txt"

    Dim file As String()
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    file = IO.File.ReadAllLines(filename)
    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim linecontain As Char

    sr = txtsr.ToString



    For Each line As String In file
        If line.Contains(sr) Then
            found = True
            Exit For
        End If
        i += 1
        If found = True Then
            MsgBox(line(i))
        End If


    Next



End Sub
```

Comment: `My code below does display a messsagebox`  Ok, so what is the question?  Please read [ask] and take the [TOUR]

Comment: When you use **ReadAllLines** you are reading the whole file into one single string, you should use **ReadLine** and read each line individually

Comment: @Zeddy I tried that and it still dont work

Comment: @Zeddy, that's not true. `ReadAllText` reads the entire file contents into a single `String`. `ReadAllLines` reads the entire file contents into a `String` array where the elements of the array are the lines of the file. There is no `ReadLine` method.

Comment: And what's `sr = txtsr.ToString`? Is `txtsr` the input TextBox control?

Answer (score 1):

You should be calling `ReadLines` here rather than `ReadAllLines`.  The difference is that `ReadAllLines` reads the entire file contents into an array first, before you can start processing any of it, while `ReadLines` doesn't read a line until you have processed the previous one.  `ReadAllLines` is good if you want random access to the whole file or you want to process the data multiple times.  `ReadLines` is good if you want to stop processing data when a line satisfies some criterion. If you're looking for a line that contains some text and you have a file with one million lines where the first line matches, `ReadAllLines` would read all one millions lines whereas `ReadLines` would only read the first.

So, here's how you display the first line that contains specific text:

```
For Each line In File.ReadLines(filePath)
    If line.Contains(substring) Then
        MessageBox.Show(line)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

With regards to your original code, your use of `i` makes no sense.  You seem to be using `i` as a line counter but there's no point because you're using a `For Each` loop so `line` contains the line. If you already have the line, why would you need to get the line by index?  Also, when you try to display the message, you are using `i` to index `line`, which means that you're going to get a single character from the line rather than a single line from the array.  If the index of the line is greater than the number of characters in the line then that is going to throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException`, which I'm guessing is what's happening to you.

This is what comes from writing code without knowing what it actually has to do first.  If you had written out an algorithm before writing the code, it would have been obvious that the code didn't implement the algorithm.  If you have no algorithm though, you have nothing to compare your code to to make sure that it makes sense.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `String.Contains` is case-sensitive so, if you want a case-insensitive comparison, you need to call `String.IndexOf`.