# Simplest way to search for an item in a file and display the line containing that item?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

**Here is my code**

*running in Console Application*

```
Sub ItemDescriptionFileSearch(ItemDescription As String)
    Dim Found As Boolean
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim line As String
    Dim FileRead As String()
    Found = False

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the Description for the item you want to preview:")
    ItemDescription = Console.ReadLine()

    FilePath = "file path here"
    FileRead = IO.File.ReadLines(FilePath)

    For Each line In FileRead
        If line.Contains(ItemDescription) Then
            Found = True     
        End If
        If Found = True Then
            Console.WriteLine(line)
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("No matching Item Description")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Error returned**
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.IO.ReadLinesIterator' to type 'System.String[]'.'

**What I've Tried**

I have tried using `ReadAllLines`, but it is giving an unwanted outcome.

I have also tried this following code using `ReadAllLines` :

```
FilePath = "file path here"
FileRead = IO.File.ReadAllLines(FilePath)

For Each line In FileRead
    If line.Contains(ItemDescription) Then
        Found = True
    End If
Next
If Found = True Then
    Console.WriteLine(line)
Else
    Console.WriteLine("No matching Item Code")
End If
```

but it gives the last line of the file as output.

I only need the program to display one line of text which contains the ItemDescription searched for.

.
This is one of the tasks for my AS Level exam coming up this next month, so working code samples would be greatly appreciated. ***Thanks !***

Comment: In the first piece of code in the question, remove the `FileRead` variable and just use `For Each line In IO.File.ReadLines(FilePath)`.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(line)` is in the wrong position in both samples. It belongs to the loop or you can add lines to a `List(Of String)` where you store your *positive results*. In this case, you don't need `Found`, just check whether your List doesn't contain elements.

Comment: @AndrewMorton thank you for that, but that only removes the unhandled exception

Comment: @Jimi I'm not sure what you mean Jimi - I took `Console.WriteLine(line)` out of the loop but the program returns every line in the file (with `"No matching Item Code"` if the ItemDescription is not found). Please use a code sample to explain.

Comment: `dim Found as integer = 0 for each line as string In File.ReadLines(FilePath) If line.Contains(ItemDescription) then Found += 1 Console.WriteLine(line) end if next Console.WriteLine(If(Found = 0, "No matching Item Code", "Items Found: " & Found.ToString()))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to search and display specific line from a text file vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49929071/how-to-search-and-display-specific-line-from-a-text-file-vb-net)

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss - I have already tried implementing that solution, but no, it doesn't work

Comment: @Jimi - Thanks Jimi, your code sample helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the code that i have found to give the desired outcome**

*solution given originally by @Jimi*

```
Dim Found As Integer = 0
    For Each line As String In IO.File.ReadLines(FilePath)
        If line.Contains(ItemDescription) Then
            Found += 1
            Console.WriteLine(line)
        End If
    Next
    If Found = 0 Then
        Console.WriteLine("No matching Item Description")
    End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following:

```vb
Dim lines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(FilePath)
Dim specificLine As String = lines.FirstOrDefault(Function(line) line.Contains(ItemDescription))

If (Not String.IsNullOrWhitespace(specificLine)) Then
    Console.WriteLine(specificLine)
End If
```

What this does is:

1. Get every line from the file
2. Use LINQ to query the array for the first instance contains a specific value
3. Check if the result of the query is not null or whitespace
4. Print the result if there was a match

Comment: It needs `Contains` rather than `=`, and it could use `ReadLines` instead of `ReadAllLines` to avoid having to read the entire file into RAM.

Comment: @AndrewMorton - I updated the equality check to using contains, but I wouldn't suspect that ReadAllLines would be an issue because the OP didn't mention the file being large. In many cases I'd prefer to write simple code that works over trying to optimize performance, it all just depends.